# PDF file not open in UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am working on the simulator any there are no apps like adobe to open the pdf files....i am using UIDocumentInteractionController to open the pdf file like below.

```
let url=URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/sai/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/425D8615-ADEC-4334-A639-C30B1E675EFA/data/Containers/Data/Application/AB3787BF-F6AC-4111-9847-A0FDC4E899F8/tmp/samplepdf.pdf")

    print("--------------------------------- str is \(url)")
    if (url != nil) {
        // Initialize Document Interaction Controller
        self.documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url)
        // Configure Document Interaction Controller
        self.documentInteractionController?.delegate = self
        // Preview PDF
        self.documentInteractionController?.presentOptionsMenu(from: self.view.frame, in: self.view, animated: true)
    }


  func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
            return self
  }
```

My screen is getting displayed like below
[No pdf is being displayed here...is it because there is no app in my simulator which could open pdf files?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnuJI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if any Simulator apps will handle pdf documents - maybe News? But you can just add a webView to a view controller and use that to view your pdf.

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
```

Do the usual safety checks on your url and then:

```
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: url as URL) as URLRequest)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a path issue.

Replace

```
let url=URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/sai/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/425D8615-ADEC-4334-A639-C30B1E675EFA/data/Containers/Data/Application/AB3787BF-F6AC-4111-9847-A0FDC4E899F8/tmp/samplepdf.pdf")
```

With

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent("samplepdf.pdf")
```

**for Swift 3/Xcode 8**

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("samplepdf.pdf") as NSURL
```

Hope that will help.